# Javascript will not load html password prompt

Tags: javascript

Here I have a website where I am trying to use internal javascript to load a prompt where unless the correct password is entered, the page will not load. Here are the relevant bits of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head onload = password_prompt()>
<script type = "text/javscript">
function password_prompt() {
    var password = window.prompt("Please enter the correct password ", ""); //password = javascript
    if (password == "javascript") { 
    }
    if ((password !== "123") && (password !== "")) {
        window.alert("You entered the wrong password! Page will now close!");
        }
    }
</script>      
    <title>My JavaScript Site - Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="layout.css" />

</head>
```

Comment: What would prevent someone from checking your JS to know the password?

Comment: What's in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Is `(password !== "")` necessary?

Comment: This is a school project

Comment: The javascript console doesn't show anything. I checked it.

Comment: If it's a school project you should learn how to do something properly, not just fake it. Why not use [`.htaccess` password authentication](http://www.htaccess-guide.com)?

Comment: The class didn't cover that... It's an introduction course.

Answer (score 0):

onload event ->
Supported HTML tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>
```

[show this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp)

and.. right syntax is `onload = "password_prompt()"` ?

right??

Comment: What happens if I want the password prompt to load before the page does

Comment: follow @qwert-e 's answer

Comment: you should make two page

Comment: prompt input password  -> correct - > redirect to 2page

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a closing html tag: `</html>`
2. Trigger your function in the `<body>` tag:
   `<body onload="password_prompt();"></body>`
3. You have a typo in "javascript", it should be:
   `<script type = "text/javascript">`

Comment: How do u make the prompt load before the page loads?

Comment: The prompt will load synchronously by default—which means anything after the function trigger will not load until the script executes. This means your script _will_ load before the page loads, at least the majority of it. You just need more content.


What you should really add is HTTP authentication, as @tadman suggested. It will execute before the page is loaded. It would have the added benefit of actually securing your page effectively.